# Change JSON String

Tags: php, json, symfony

I have a JSON string I want to change it.

The JSON string looks like

```
string '[{"id":"AT.02708872.T"},{"id":"DE.60232348.A"}]' (length=114)
```

I want to convert this JSON to

```
string '[{"id":"AT02708872"},{"id":"DE60232348"}]' (length=114)
```

So I want to remove the dots and the last letter. I am using Symfony2 (PHP)

Anyone has any idea how can I do it.

Thanks

Comment: Decode it to an array, iterate over it and modify it, encode it back to json.

Comment: You want do it in JavaScript or Php?

Comment: use $result = json_decode($string) and loop trought $result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decode, modify, re-encode.

```
<?php

$json = '[{"id":"AT.02708872.T"},{"id":"DE.60232348.A"}]';

// Decode the JSON data into an array of objects. 
// Symfony probably will have some JSON handling methods so you could look at
// those to keep the code more Symfony friendly.
$array = json_decode($json);


// Loop through the array of objects so you can modify the ID of 
// each object. Note the '&'. This is calling $object by reference so
// any changes within the loop will persist in the original array $array
foreach ($array as &$object)
{
    // Here we are stripping the periods (.) from the ID and then removing the last
    // character with substr()
    $object->id = substr(str_replace('.', '', $object->id), 0, -1);
}

// We can now encode $array back into JSON format
$json = json_encode($array);

var_dump($json);
```

There is probably native JSON handling within Symfony2 so you may want to check that out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help it worked, can you please explain your answer a bit to me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript regular expression to replace the unwanted elements with blank string. You should, however, do this before you parse the string to php object.

Answer (score 0):

Is it one string?  Run a regular expression on it:

```
<?
   $str =  '[{"id":"AT.02708872.T"},{"id":"DE.60232348.A"}]' ;
   echo preg_replace('/\.[A-Z]"/','"',$str);
?>
```

This is assuming that all your id's end in . 1 capital letter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '[{"id":"AT.02708872.T"},{"id":"DE.60232348.A"}]';

$json = json_decode($json, true);

$result = array();
foreach($json as $item) {
    $tmp = explode('.', $item['id']);
    $result[] = array('id' => $tmp[0] . $tmp[1]);
}

$result = json_encode($result);
echo $result;
```